MedusaJS subscribe to payment.updated event
I'm trying to subscribe to payment.updated event in MedusaJs, but I can't import a PaymentService to use like this:
export const config: SubscriberConfig = {
  event: OrderService.Events.PLACED,
};

when I try to import I get deprecated interface.
